# Selenium hanging forever while finding the preceding-sibling elements of 1st element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get the preceding element Of and from the same webelement. But as the webelement is the first webelement, there are no preceding-sibling elements, the process hangs forever.
And as I am trying to find the webelements from another webelement (rather than using driver), the implicit wait is not working as well.

```
@BeforeTest
public void init(){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://account.box.com/login");
}


    @Test
public void testWebElem(){
    WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-form']/div/h2"));
    System.out.println(getPositionOfWebElem(source));
}


private int getPositionOfWebElem(WebElement elem){
    String xpathExpressionFollowing = "./following-sibling::*";
    System.out.println("xPath Expression :: " + xpathExpressionFollowing);
    List<WebElement> elemsFollowing = elem.findElements(By.xpath(xpathExpressionFollowing));
    printWebelems(elemsFollowing);
    String xpathExpression = "./preceding-sibling::*";
    System.out.println("xPath Expression :: " + xpathExpression);
    List<WebElement> elemsts = elem.findElements(By.xpath(xpathExpression));
    printWebelems(elemsts);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce your implicit wait since 2000 seconds is very L-O-N-G wait!Else webdriver will wait for 2000 seconds to find the preceding elements which isn't present!BTW if your fond of 4 digit integers, use TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS

Below Snippet worked for me

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class Test22{

WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void init(){
 driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.get("https://account.box.com/login");
}

@Test
  public void testWebElem(){
WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login-form']/div/h2"));
System.out.println(getPositionOfWebElem(source));
}


private int getPositionOfWebElem(WebElement elem){
String xpathExpressionFollowing = "./following-sibling::*";
System.out.println("xPath Expression :: " + xpathExpressionFollowing);
List<WebElement> elemsFollowing = elem.findElements(By.xpath(xpathExpressionFollowing));
System.out.println(elemsFollowing.size());
String xpathExpression = "./preceding-sibling::*";
System.out.println("xPath Expression :: " + xpathExpression);
List<WebElement> elemsts = elem.findElements(By.xpath(xpathExpression));
System.out.println(elemsts.size());
return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: oops sorry! :p Just too habitual of using time in milliseconds!;p

Comment: @DhaneshKhurana: Please accept the answer if I was able to answer your query!